# Where to put the Dismiss button for a modal TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, modal-dialog, uistoryboardsegue, tabbarcontroller

I launch a Tab Bar Controller from my view with a segue.  After editing the passed data, I need to dismiss the tab controller. The storyboard in Xcode won't allow me to add a Dismiss button on the Tab Controller (and shown on all the tabs.) Do I have to have a separate Dismiss button on each tab view? That seems rather clunky.

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each view which is connected to a tab bar in the Tab Bar Controller is a completely separate view. The tab bar just holds them together. If you would like to have a back button, you do have to have a separate button or gesture action on each view in the tab bar.

However, you can easily dismiss the view with code instead of having to add four extra segues.

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
```

That line will dismiss your current view controller.

Comment: the question says it's presented modally, not pushed

Comment: Clunky it is, I guess.